# Call a function of GameScene in GameViewController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the function revivePlayer() in the GameScene and i'm trying to call it from within the GameViewController. I have the follow solution in the GameViewController right now: `GameScene().revivePlayer()`
This code does call the revivePlayer() function but is does nothing to the game. Although if I add `print("test")` inside the revivePlayer() function, it does print "test" in the console, but the rest of the code inside the revivePlayer() function seems to not get invoked.

That's what I have in the GameViewController, I removed some irrelevant code and also for information I use rewarded Video Ad from AdMob and the function rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose() is invoked when the ad is closed:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsPhysics = false
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        videoAd = createVideoAd()
        GameScene().revivePlayer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameScene().revivePlayer()` is calling the `revivePlayer` function on a *new* instance of `GameScene`, not the game scene that is presented in your view controller.

To resolve this issue, keep a reference to the game scene that is presented and call `revivePlayer` on that instance.

Something like this should work, although it depends on exactly how you set up your scene.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var skView: SKView!

    var gameScene = GameScene()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        skView.presentScene(gameScene)

    }

    func myFunction() {
        gameScene.revivePlayer()
    }

}
```

---

**Edit #1**

One solution to the comment below is to use `SKView`'s `scene` property to get a reference to the currently presented scene.

```
if let gameScene = skView.scene as? GameScene {
    gameScene.revivePlayer()
}
```

---

**Edit #2**

You'll also need to keep a reference to your `SKView`.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ... {

    var skView: SKView! // declare a property to keep a reference to the SKView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            skView = view // assign the SKView to our new property

            ...

        }
    }

    ...

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        videoAd = createVideoAd()
        if let gameScene = skView.scene as? GameScene { // check to see if the current scene is the game scene
            gameScene.revivePlayer() // revive the player
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't do it like that because in the viewDidLoad() I present the menuScene and not GameScene so that when you start the game the MenuScene is presented. I call the present GameScene in the menuScene. Is there a different way to make this work?

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Ok, in that case, there are a few different options. The simplest is to use the `SKView`'s `scene` property to get the currently presented scene. I'll edit my answer to explain with an example.

Comment: Sorry but I cant get it to work, could you maybe add some more code to the example? and also I want to mention that I call GameScene().revivePlayer() inside a function in GameViewController, I don't want to call GameScene().revivePlayer() instantly when the GameScene is loaded

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Can you add the code you are currently using? It will be quicker to work from your current solution instead of trying to guess what your code is like.

Comment: @LukasDomeisen As I stated in my answer, replace `GameScene().revivePlayer()` with `if let gameScene = skView.scene as? GameScene { gameScene.revivePlayer() }`.

Comment: @LukasDomeisen And you'll also need to create a new property called `skView`. I'll edit my answer again.